# Making website use subfolder as index page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, migration

I'm currently working on a site that uses a custom CMS framework. I'm not 100% sure how it works but I see that .htaccess(in the root directory) "calls"(redirects) to a .php file that launches the rest of the site.

So the current template of the site in use from ftp looks like this:

```
website.com/html/templates/oldtemplate
```

I've created a new directory in the templates folder called wordpress with all the needed wp files inside.

Using .htaccess I want the site to use the new wordpress folder as its starting point.

www.website.com should now be using the file path below:

```
website.com/html/templates/wordpress
```

I tried looking for solutions for this but the closest answers I found was having the website with a subdirectory such as: www.website.com/wordpress

I've tried code such as:

```
DirectoryIndex templates/wordpress/index.php
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /templates/wordpress/index.php
```

But to no avail as only the "under construction" loads without the background image and I could not access the admin panel.

Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding how .htaccess or wordpress works?

Comment: If WordPress is the new "starting point" why are you keeping the old site? Don't try to wrap it inside another site.

Comment: @Walf The old site is in a folder but htaccess no longer points to it so as far as I know it doesn't interfere with anything that I'm doing. I just want my wordpress site to work but it seems to be stuck on the under construction page.